# How to execute a Solidity function via Web3.js?

Tags: solidity, web3js

I have been trying to figure out how to call a simple function in Solidity, passing a simple string parameter over to it. I am at my wits' end, I have scoured the Internet and tried virtually every method and operator imaginable that they cite out there. Nothing seems to work.

The code in Solidity is:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

contract Name {
    string public name;

    function setName(string _name) public {
        name = _name;
    }
}
```

I am trying to pass the string "hello" to it and then read it back. Like so:

```
console.log("Calling function with parameters:")
contractInstance.setName.call("hello", (error, result) => {
    if (!error) {
        console.log("parameters passed")
    }
})
console.log("Reading public variable:")
console.log(contractInstance.name.call())
console.log("End of story")
```

It comes back empty! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See the answer in the referenced duplicate. You can’t use call() to alter state.

Comment: Thanks so much, Adam! The sendTransaction approach works. Finally! Sweet!